# Database relational diagram check

Tags: database, diagram, relational

I created a database relational diagram for water-equipment rental. My professor sent project back with "relational errors in database" comments. I cant find any error. Can you look and give me advice?

http://screenshooter.net/102227472/mkadqsk

thank you for all

Comment: No primary key defined on `rental`?

Comment: Why don't you email your professor and ask him what the errors are?

Comment: maybe it's primary key's on rental faults.

@jwg My project was returned with errors and when I asked about what kind I only get "relational errors" answer :/

Comment: For a rental system, does your professor also want you to consider what status rentals are at? (Overdue, booked but not collected, not returned, damaged, etc)?  ... Or does he expect Paradox type table design with the columns all being one combined primary key?

Comment: I don't think so. I had only project topic with:

- PK/FK
- One to many/ many to many relationship
- ERD+physical diagram


It's only for database basic in access so I was shocked when I receive my project status

Answer (score 1):

`type` should be renamed to `type_id` in the link (relationship) to your Type table

Comment: hmmm I am not sure it's name's fault. But I will try fix that this way

Comment: I agree, its probably not the name. But your professor was being obscure with his comment, so I thought I'd take a punt on consistency

Comment: yes you are right so I will try add a primary key on rental and fix the names. I hope it will pass. Thanks guys :)